# How to query a mongo collection having stored dates as strings of a certain format?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a mongo collection and each document in that collection has a date string in the following format:

```
{
    "etd": "15-Mar-21"
}
```

I want to query and retrieve only those documents from this collection whose date is greater than or equal to **15-Mar-21**.

Can anyone please guide me, as to how I can write a Mongo query for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation to first add a field to all the docs with the converted date using the `$dateFromString` directive.

```
{
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$etd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The above will add a field `date` to each doc (just for the duration of the query) that will store the Date objects that correspond to the their string representation. So `"15-Mar-21"` will become `ISODate("2021-03-15T00:00:00Z")`

And then just use `$match` to match all docs where `date` is greater than a given date. So here is the full aggreagion:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$etd"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gt: ISODate("2021-03-15T00:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LSHcukh05jk